# Add data to a json file in terraform

Tags: json, terraform

I am not a software guy, but I am preparing a small script for delarative onboarding work using terraform. The declaration is in a json file and it is send to the device through terraform. But I do not want to keep the sensitive data like passwords and secret keys in the json file. I want to inject them from a seperate file in a vault to the json file when I  am executing it in terraform. I can use terraform to read the data from a vault or a s3 bucket, but I am not sure how to add it to the json declaration. I saw in terraform there is  a functions like jsondecode and jsonencode. But I am not sure whether they will be any use to my requirement.
Could someone help me on this please ?

Thansk.

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear. Can you provide more details of what you want to do? Examples of your code showing your current attempt with errors would be helpful.

Comment: Hi.. So actually I have not tried any manipulations to the json file as I am not sure how to do that. so I have the following code to pass the json file ,

resource "bigip_do" "gns-do" {
  do_json    = file("./env/poc/ltm/lbr01.json") 
  timeout    = 30
  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_180_seconds]
}

I need to pass those variable to the json file before sending the declaration from this code. I was thinking using  a python code to do that modification to the json file and save the output to a temp location and pick it from that location.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is something which could help you?
Create a data source which loads your template file, here you can pass in some vars.

some examples for variales:

```
data "template_file" "my_template" {
  template = templatefile("template.json", {
    foo         = "bar"
    another_foo = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id
    more_foo    = var.my_variable
  })
}
```

The template file could look like this:

```
{
  "Value":   "123",
  "value_2": "${foo}",
  "value_3": "${another_foo}",
  "value_4": ${more_foo},
}
```

Comment: ah.. cool.. thanks. Let me check :)

Comment: @RukshanK You probably also want to look at the `jsonencode()` function.

Comment: Yeah.. I also think so.. I tried it initially.. but it did not work for me. I tried decoding the existing json using jsonedcode() function and encode with new variables using jsonencode(). Actually it did not work for me.. But will check the documentation also for that. Thank you very much for the support...